# Not able to know to which SIM sms was received

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, sms, dual-sim

**Short Description:**
I am using JellyBean in a dual SIM featured phone. I am using Go SMS software also standard Messaging also I used. I find it peculiar to know that there is no such feature to know to which SIM an SMS was received.

**Detailed Issue:**
I am using XOLO A1000 Dual SIM phone which is running in JellyBean. I am using two SIM cards one is by Aircel and another is by Airtel who are two different service providers in India.

In my inbox (threads of SMS) either using Messaging app or by Go SMS app all SMS are stored by senders. Now my problem is when I receive a new spam SMS I am not able to know to which SIM that SMS was sent to. To my SIM1 or to my SIM2. Both the apps doesn't show any marking to distinguish that. I even checking 'Message Details' it doesn't contain destination number detail.

This is important if I need to file complaint against spamming. Any help will be much appreciated. This is basic required feature but I wonder why I am not able to help myself, I even Googled it and found nothing.

Comment: Maybe try an alternative messaging app that specifically caters for dual sim, its likely that the app Go SMS and Messaging just cannot handle dual sim...?

Comment: You got it right, I tried Youni sms app and it favors me to great extend :) It not only solved my problem it itself stands out to be very powerful messaging app like GO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, At last I found the answer keeping @t0mm13b as inspiration. The problem is on the Messaging app and Go sms app. So I had to find out a suitable app for my need. [Youni SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snda.youni&hl=en) is one such and it is working so great. It is clearly marking as sim1 or sim2 for every SMS received and sent.

Comment: The same problem exists in apps like Textra and Messenger in Motorola Moto G2..

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem here is that these apps are assuming, rightly so, that there will always only be one destination number (that is, only one SIM). Android doesn't officially support dual SIMs. From StackOverflow:

> **[Android dual SIM card API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305407/android-dual-sim-card-api)**
>
> ...the dual sim features are available but not documented and hence not officially supported. Having said that it doesn't mean that it will not be usable, it just means that android is not liable to support [that] functionality.

Also,

> **[Dual SIM card Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android?rq=1)**
>
> The current Android platform does not have support for multiple SIMs. A device with such support has been customized for this, so you will need to get information from that device's manufacturer for any facilities they have to interact with it.

[A third question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16279210) was even asked specifically about building an app for dual SIM handsets that has gone unanswered, likely for this reason. So, while it sounds like a reasonable expectation, without official support or APIs for developers to use I wouldn't expect many apps to account for two destination numbers.

From a consumer perspective this means that we're at the mercy of manufacturers to develop apps that function correctly with two SIM cards. Unfortunately it sounds like the your phone's stock messaging app isn't fitting this bill. Try reaching out to XOLO.

Comment: Actually, I was just looking into this, and there is a column called SUBSCRIPTION_ID that does exactly that. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns#SUBSCRIPTION_ID

Answer (score 0):

Since Android doesn't appear to have an easy way to get this information, have you looked into getting the messaging information from your phone bill from your carrier?

I'm not sure if all carriers do this, but on the carriers I've used, if you receive a "detailed" bill with complete usage records it will have a list of time and date and phone number for all incoming texts. Sometimes this information can be accessed through the carrier's website as well. If your carrier(s) support such detailed billing, it should be easy to correlate between the phone records from your carrier and the messages on your phone.